# Possible asynchronous error using mongoose and express - db.once('open', function(){console.log('connection opened')}) not reached

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple express app with mongodb

I am trying to query the database based on parameters passed with a get request, however while console.log('==params==', params) is reached, console.log('connection opened') is not. I suspect it's an asynchronous problem but I can't fully see why as I'm not even passing any variables around

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var db = require('./modules/db')
var logic = require('./modules/logic')

var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.get('/phrase', function(req, res){
  logic(req.query);
  console.log('req.query', req.query)
})
```

db.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('...');
var db = mongoose.connection;
module.exports = db;
```

logic.js

```
var db = require('./db')

var logic = function(params){
  console.log('==params==', params)
  db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('connection opened')
  })  
}

module.exports = logic;
```

Comment: `db.once('open'` fires once when the database is initialized, you don't have to wrap every query in that handler, and by the time the route fires, the `once` event has probably long since been fired.

Comment: Ah! Must read the documentation closer - should have worked that out. Thank you :)

Comment: The documentation isn't very clear on that, but it says something like *"For brevity, let's assume that all following code is within this callback."*, which means all code that uses the DB should be in the `once-open` handler, to make sure the DB is ready. It's not an event that can be used for anything else really.